# No quick-fix for missing import when devloping python in vs code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am currently migrating my python projects from pycharm to vscode and trying to figure out how to auto-complete missing imports (a feature that worked in pycharm out of the box). Apperently this can be done by using quick-fixes offered by vscode, e.g. if I type `path` in an empty python source file, vscode offeres me several quick-fixes to add the required dependency (e.g. `from os import path`).

Unfortunately this only works for built-in packages, because if I try to auto-complete the import for the `create_engine` function of the sqlalchemy package, vscode doesn't provide any quick-fixes at all (I made sure that the sqlalchemy package is installed in the python environment used by my project).

I have installed the python (v2023.14.0) and pylance (v2023.8.30) vscode plugin and I am using Python 3.10.2.

Am I missing a package or vscode setting?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons and different solutions that could work. Like: reinstalling python extension, check pylance settings, clear cached intellisense data.

Answer (score 0):

For this case they appear in [**Quick Fix**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_code-actions-quick-fixes-and-refactorings), you can click on the yellow light bulb next to the code to turn it on, or you can use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

[image]

**EDIT:**

**Make sure you have selected the *correct* interpreter environment.** This works perfectly on my machine.

[image]

You can use `pip show sqlalchemy` to view the installation information of `sqlalchemy`.

[image]